# How to change the size of an image coming from an API call

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to resize an image coming from an API call? I am extracting an image from an API and trying to insert into a div on the page. The API is "NASA image of the day" and its a new image from nasa each day. Sometimes the image is vertical, and sometimes the image is horizontal depending on the day. What is the best way to handle this situation? I don't want the image to exceed the div it is inside of (40rem x 40rem), and right now the image posts really big on the screen and isn't contained inside of the div at all.

```
HTML:
<section class="section" id="section--1">
      <div class="section__title">
        <div class="title--info">
          <h2 class="section__description">Image of the day <button>view</button></h2>
          <h3 class="section__header">
            View the "image of the day" taken by NASA satellites in space
          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="parent__el"></div>

        
      <!-- <figure class="space__photo">
        <img src="/img/space.jpg" alt=""/>
      </figure> -->

CSS:

.parent__el {
  height: 40rem;
  width: 40rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

JavaScript:

const imageContainer = document.querySelector('.parent__el')

const loadImage = async function() {
    try {
        //  1) loading recipe
        const res = await fetch('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=BSw3P3LRHk0brFlI5xMlVkaTdwUZuA3arh0A5ziV');
        const data = await res.json();

        if(!res.ok) throw new Error(`${data.message} (${res.status})`);
      
     
        console.log(data) 

        // 2) rendering recipe
        const markup = `
            <div class="space__photo">
              <img src="${data.url}" alt="" />
            </div>
        `;

        imageContainer.innerHTML = markup;

    } catch(err) {
        alert(err)
    }
    
}

loadImage()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try setting the image as the background image of your `space_photo` container:

```
 const markup = `
        <div class="space__photo" style="background-image: url('${data.url}'); background-size:cover;">
        </div>
    `;
```

You would then have to give the class "space__photo" an appropriate size though (height and width 100% for example, so it stretches the entire length of your parent_el)

Answer (score 0):

give your image an id, "img".
in your div rendering part, do this:

```
let img = document.getElementById("img")
if(img.style.height >= img.style.width) {
img.style.height = '40px'
} else {
img.style.width = '40px'
}
```

This makes it so when the image is verticle, it renders it as 40px height. When it is horizontal, it is 40px width.

Comment: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style'). This is the error I am receiving

Comment: Try removing the .style, I am recieving conflicting info from different people, sorry.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then try doing .clientWidth and .clientStyle instead of .style.width...

Comment: no matter what I put, I receive the error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'X'). This occurred when style was removed and when X=.clientWidth. Is it possible that since its an async function that we are trying to style an image that hasn't been received yet?

Comment: maybe...  try on your function loadImage run, `loadimage().then(a=>{})`

Comment: with the setting style inside the .then

Comment: Doesn't work. I will keep trying different things